# Can I redirect the output of a program to cat with a pipe?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, cat, subshell

I have a folder with three files and basic contents:

```
$ tail *
==> file1 <==
file 1 contents

==> file2 <==
file 2 contents

==> file3 <==
file 3 contents
```

I would like to see the contents of the latest file using `cat`.  I tried using it like this:

```
$ ls -ctr | tail -1
file3

$ ls -ctr | tail -1 | cat
file3
```

but as you can see, it only prints the name of the last file.  I thought the pipe would take the output of `tail` and process the file with that name, like it does with the subshell command:

```
$ cat $(ls -ctr | tail -1)
file 3 contents
```

Why does the redirection method not work, and is there a way to accomplish this with pipes instead of the subshell?

Comment: Also you should read ["Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  If you're doing it interactively you might be fine, but if you're scripting, please don't do this.

Comment: More generally, though, you should clear up the difference between a command's *arguments* and a command's *input*.

Comment: `cat` outputs its input, so if the input is `file3`, the output will be `file3`; whether it's a file name or anything else. `echo file | cat` is quite different from `cat file`. To open the *output of a command* as file name, use `cat $(command)`.

Comment: @U.Windl Regarding _`cat` outputs its input, so if the input is `file3`, the output will be `file3`_, I'm not sure what you mean.  If I type `cat file3` I see the contents of the file, not the string `file3`.

Comment: "Input" is "stdin" (not to be mixed with "parameter"). You would enter `cat`, *then* type `file3`, and the EOF sequence (^D) to terminate the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
set   ./file[123]            ### set an arg array of the glob resolution
while [ "${2+:}" ]           ### while there are at least 2 args
do    [ "$1" -nt "$2" ] &&   ### if $1 is newer than $2 then ...
      set "$@" "$1"; shift   ### reset the array to itself + $1; shift regardless
done; cat <"$1"              ### after loop cat $1 or report no glob match
```

Comment: I know you like simple "code only" answers and think they are self-explanatory...but they really could be greatly improved by adding explanations.  :)  At an absolute minimum if you just briefly said the *names* of the different features you are using, it would then allow an interested newcomer to at least know what words to put into a search engine to figure out your code.

Comment: @Wildcard - i welcome edits and would thank you for any you cared to contribute. but, as usual, you have a point...

Comment: Accepted because of the clear explanation of the code given.

Comment: @user1717828 - please look again at the edit - this fixes the subtle bug of the previous snippet's tendency to forever loop when `${1}t` == `${2}t`. This version will always prefer the last of two such in the lexical sort order.

Answer (score 7):

You want to use the `xargs` command:

```
$ ls -ctr | tail -1 | xargs cat
```

This will take the STDOUT of the `tail -1` command, and instead of using it as STDIN for the `cat` command will use it as options to the `cat` command.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
less $(ls -ctr | tail - 1)
```

(the `$(...)` isn't universal, you might need to substitute backticks). Change `less` to taste.

Comment: > with pipes *instead of the subshell*?

Comment: @user1717828, a subshell is definitely cheaper that launching `xargs`